# Validation for 2nd monday from today

Tags: validation, date, formula

I am new to SharePoint and I'm trying to do a validation for greater than or equal to the 2nd Monday from today.

I'm creating a work request form and I want to make sure they can't make a due date sooner than the 2nd Monday. So If a request is put in the week of 1/11 the soonest turnaround is 1/29. Also, I would like to make that the default value.

How would I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not **1/26** is the soonest?  Frist Monday from 1/11 is 1/18 and the 2nd Monday from 1/11 is 1/25. So, 1/26 should be a valid DueDate. Can you clarify this?

Comment: because depending on the workload for the week 1 day may not be enough. So if they are submitting work for that week, I can submit a schedule to my team. So 1/29th is not the most important thing, but yes you are correct 1/26 would be valid. As long as I can make sure due dates are not sooner than the 2nd monday, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Form validation formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(DueDate)),IF(DueDate>(TODAY()+(7-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1+7)),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

1. Find days from TODAY() to the first Monday using WEEKDAY(date,return_type), where date is TODAY(), return_type=2. It returns weekdays numbered 1 (Monday) through 7 (Sunday)
2. Add days (step 1) plus 1 to TODAY() to get the first Monday and then add 7 days more to get the date of the 2nd Monday
3. Valid [DueDate]s are dates that are greater than the date of the 2nd Monday

---

Soonest Validate DueDates assuming StartDate=TODAY()

[image]